# Command binding on ListView context menu not firing (not found)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, command

I have a binding problem on my ListView I got an error :

```
Binding: 'OnEdit' property not found on 'ContactsViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem.Command'
```

Here is the XAML (maybe I made an error with the reference) :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Contactium.ContactsPage"
         x:Name="ContactsPageContent">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
...
<TextCell.ContextActions>
      <MenuItem  Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnEdit, Source={x:Reference ContactsPageContent}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="EDITER" IsDestructive="True"/>
      <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.OnDelete, Source={x:Reference ContactsPageContent}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="SUPPRIMER"/>
</TextCell.ContextActions>
...
```

Here is the ViewModel (ContactsPageContent) :

```
public Command OnEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    return new Command(() =>
    {
         Debug.Write("OK");
    });
}

public Command OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    return new Command(() =>
    {
         Debug.Write("OK");
    });
}
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Try to write your command this way `public ICommand OnEdit { get; set; }
OnEdit= new Command(EditAction);
private void EditAction(object obj)
{
  Debug.Write("OK");
}`

Comment: It works, I have to use a property so, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write up your `Command` in the form of property as below

```
public ICommand OnEdit { get; set; }
OnEdit= new Command(EditAction); 
private void EditAction(object obj)
{ 
 Debug.Write("OK"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<ListView x:Name="Cities" <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <ViewCell.ContextActions>

        <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand ,Source={x:Reference Name=Cities}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True">

        </MenuItem>

      </ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

and in your ViewModel you can use this:

```
DeleteCommand = new Command<Category>(async (selected) =>
            {});
```